# The number of chains of chordal graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a saturated chain $G_0 \subset G_1 \subset \cdots \subset G_m$ of graphs on $n$ labelled vertices, where $G_i$ has $i$ edges, and $m = {{n}\choose {2}}$. Altogether there are $m!$ such chains of graphs (they are also known as "graph processes") and they form an interesting topic of study.

Recall that $G$ is chordal if all induced cycles in $G$ are 3-gons.

### The question

Let $f(n)$ be the number of such chains where all graphs $G_i$ are chordal. What is the value of $f(n)$? a) for small values of $n$? b) what is its asymptotic behaviour? c) Is there an exact formula?

Of course $f(n) \le {{n} \choose {2}}!$, and it is easy to see that $f(n) \ge \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k!$.

Variations: We can also ask about a) saturated chains of perfect graphs, b) saturated chains of chordal graphs whose complement is also chordal.

### Motivation

For a saturated chain of graphs $G_0 \subset G_1 \subset \cdots \subset G_m$ we can look at the vector $(v_0,v_1,...,v_{n-1})$ where $v_k$ is the number of indices $j$ where $G_{j+1}$ has $k$ additional triangles compared to $G_j$. Such vectors introduced by Beus in 1970 (in the context of sorting algorithms) are interesting parameters of saturated chains of graphs and the case of chordal graphs is precisely the case where the vector is $(n-1,n-2,\dots,1)$.

#### Remark:

$f(3)=6$, and $f(4)=576$. I am curious to know the values of $f(5)$ and $f(6)$.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you look instead at "chains of connected graphs" (or really, connected graph plus isolated vertices, depending on how you look at it) then you're counting shellings of the complete graph, and this question was asked (a couple times) on MO previously: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297411/counting-connected-edge-orderings-shellings-of-the-complete-graph

Comment: It is at most $c^{n^2}m!$ for certain $c<1$: we may choose $\Omega(n^2)$ edge-disjoint complete graphs on 4 vertices, and each of them have several forbidden orders of edges appearance. These events are independent.

Comment: I think the g(3) in your remark should be f(3).

Comment: It could be computed up to about f(12) fairly easily, using the isomorph-invariance of chordalness (choldality?) Alas I can't do it in the near future.

Comment: Dear @BrendanMcKay, I waited since the early 80s so anything which is little -o of 40 years can be considered as "near future" :) Thanks, Sam. I vaugely remember that the guess $(n!)^{n−2}$ based on $n=3,4$, did not come through, but maybe it reflects a weighted enumeration of some kind.

Comment: I couldn't resist, see my answer.

Comment: Just a comment: the chordal graphs whose complements are also chordal are the split graphs, i.e., its vertices can be partitioned into two classes where one is clique and the other is an independent set. Understanding the question for split graphs might be useful for answering question b) since almost all chordal graphs are split graphs, see  https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700023077. If this is what motivated Variation b) in the first place, then my apologies for stating the obvious.

Comment: Many thanks, Nathan. I forgot that split graphs are precisely chordal graphs whose complements are chordal. Certainly this gives more motivation (and hope) for b).

Comment: @NathanLindzey In any case the reference to split graph shows that the asymptotic behavior is $\exp (c n^2 \log n)$ since once you added the edges of a clique of size $n/2$ you can next add the edges between its vertices and the other vertices in an arbitrary order.

Comment: I remember, and just checked, that "almost all chordal graphs are split graphs" is one of those asymptotic facts that are in no hurry to happen. Up as far as the number of labelled chordal graphs is known ($n=13$), the ratio is still heading towards 0 at an apparently exponential rate.  Similarly the number of chordal chains is growing faster than the number of split chains by an extra factor of 4 at each step. For $n=12$ there are 6458 times as many chordal chains as split chains.  All this emphasises the danger of the law of small numbers.

Comment: Of course, even if the total number of graphs is asymptotically equal, it doesn't follow that the number of chains is asymptotically equal.  There are more ways for a chordal chain to get started and this advantage will remain no matter how many vertices there are.

Comment: Brendan, would it be easy now by your program to have a similar table for $n \le 12$ for the case of chains of split graphs?

Comment: Gil, define $c(n)$ by the number of split chains is $n^{c(n)n^2}$. The value is steadily rising and by $n=14$ has passed $\frac12$. I believe that a lower bound $\liminf c(n) \ge \frac12+o(1)$ follows by recursive application of your idea. I'm guessing that $c(n)$ converges to a number around $0.8$, which is pretty high considering that $\binom{n}{2}! = n^{(1+o(1))n^2}$.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a general answer but the big numbers don't fit properly into a comment.

```
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1
f(3) = 6
f(4) = 576
f(5) = 1416960
f(6) = 120678543360
f(7) = 455010170456862720
f(8) = 95371866538619173904056320
f(9) = 1383866987105877308750365304858542080
f(10) = 1716187027583005555045945024371317843956845772800
f(11) = 221917018834976627508152930913765491170568412125060985539788800
f(12) = 3598055237740601485367382153175891099609454479883844294426214728495086488780800
f(13) = 8665460290021468438320782226358244848272843476236433280013965605190231652374443764439998581964800
```

The last two took about 10 minutes and 5 hours.

For a graph $G$ let $g(G)$ be 0 if $G$ is not chordal and equal to the number of chordal chains back to the empty graph otherwise.

Set $g({\rm empty})=1$ and for one member $G$ of each isomorphism class of nonempty chordal graph in non-decreasing order of the number of edges, do
$$ g(G) := \sum_{e\in E(G)} g(G-e). $$
The answer is $g(K_n)$.
No adjustment for automorphism group size is needed. The only technical requirement is recognising $G-e$ as isomorphic to a previous graph.

The program can handle any class of graphs closed under isomorphism provided they all fit into memory at once.

On request, here is the corresponding table for split graphs.

```
s(1) = 1
s(2) = 1
s(3) = 6
s(4) = 480
s(5) = 719040
s(6) = 28111985280
s(7) = 39667596799259520
s(8) = 2716101119587792215121920
s(9) = 11750142295253741381979240922398720
s(10) = 4059370170952132363824590307446791630779187200
s(11) = 138004666315436722628999805261994204164032807656029840998400
s(12) = 557103455087735168484078548670473120844063643381325957791547628642631680000
s(13) = 316753104615638650562235298836069531430557783996203420700809420563227053308369342951115980800
s(14) = 29665849491651526562732309913886504922801500810240504259322068041948739753073885726711112718885233432115281920000
```

Comment: Dear Brendan, wonderful! thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose that asymptotically we can wonder if it is $e^{cn^2}$ or $e^{cn^2 \log n}$ or something else.

Comment: It is $e^{c n^2 \log n}$ already for chains of split graphs. (See comments for the question.)