# Computing the number of ways to delete vertices sequentially without disconnecting a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Given a finite connected graph on $n$ vertices, we are trying to count the number of ways to label the vertices $1$ to $n$ so that deleting them sequentially in that order never disconnects the graph. (Let us call this the *sweepout number* until we find a reference elsewhere.)

For example, for $K_n$ this is $n!$, for a path on $n$ vertices this is $2^{n-1}$. These are clearly the largest and smallest possible values. Other values:

- For a star with $n-1$ leaves, the answer is $2(n-1)!$
- For a cycle graph, the answer is $n2^{n-2}$

The answers are sometimes divisible; for instance, for the 4-vertex graphs we get 8, 12, 14, 16, 20, 24. (The answer is automatically even.)

This must have been studied, but we can't find the key word. It seems possibly related to the Tutte polynomial.

Can this be computed in any reasonable way?

**Update:** Divisibility does not continue for large graphs. For an example that also hints at the motivation, consider the dual graph to the division of Pennsylvania into congressional districts. (This is a graph with 18 vertices). The sweepout number for this graph is 10,672,157,119,848, which is not round.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to counting shelling orders of the line graph of $G$, isn't it? See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297411/counting-connected-edge-orderings-shellings-of-the-complete-graph and https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10263 for discussions of some (infinite families of) special cases.

Comment: @Alex, it does not seem equivalent. Consider a path on $3$ vertices 1—2—3. The vertices can be numbered in 4 ways. But the line graph is 12—23, it has only one edge so only one shelling.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but worth mentioning that there are various well-studied classes of graphs (e.g. threshold graphs, chordal graphs) that are defined recursively in terms of adding a single vertex at a time.

Comment: @Jukka good catch, thanks! It still feels to me like there's something involving shellability (or vertex-decomposability) going on here --- $n2^{n-2}$ is the number of shelling orders of the cycle graph.

Comment: Alex, I agree that the shellability (ordering edges) seems relevant to the question here (ordering vertices), but it is not clear what exactly the connection is.

Comment: For trees obtained by identifying the endpoints of three intervals, the count appears to always be a multiple of $4.$ But it can be $4p$ with $p$ prime. For paths of length $4,7,10$ joined this way (so $19$ vertices) I get $4\cdot 4172117.$ I didn't see that phenomen  past that as far as I looked (up to $10,20,30$.) If the graph has high symmetry, that will be reflected in the number.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz , we looked more and noticed the numbers are not round in general, see some more data in the post. I didn't understand which phenomenon you were seeing or not.

Comment: @DylanThurstan Let $c_{ijk}$ be the number of deletion sequences for a tree with three leaves at distances $i  \leq j \leq k$ from the unique degree $3$ point. Based (now) on  all the counts with $1 \leq i \leq k\leq 50$ (so $\binom{51}3$ cases) I see that these are always a multiple of $4.$ The phenomenon I meant was that of $c=4p$ with $p$ prime.  It happens $40$ times over that range , the last being for $c_{3,5,50},c_{3,6,9}$ and $c_{3,26,37}$. Also, there are $634$ cases with $c$ being $4$ times an odd number, The last being someplace with $i=16.$

Comment: It is kind of a dumb computation, but faster than I thought. Going out to $100$ I also see the $4p$ phenomenon at $c_{3,37,82}$ and  $c_{6,59,65}$ but no place else. Since $c_{i,j,k}=c_{i-1,j,k}+c_{i,j-1,k}+c_{i,j,k-1}$, If all four are multiples of $4$, then an  even number are $4$ times an odd.  Nonetheless, I don't see that past $c_{32,33,65}.$

Comment: You probably already know this, but there are a few more infinite families where it is possible to get a formula: For example formula for the Bipartite graph $K_{2,n}$ (and $n \geq 3$) the sweepout number is $2 \sum_{i=0}^{n} i! c(n,i) 2 (n-i-1)!$ Just by considering paths in the part with degree two vertices and then at some point the graph becomes a star graph then one can your formula in that case.

Comment: Sorry it should read $2 \sum_{i=0}^{n} i! c(n,i) 2 (n-i+2)!$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there is a simple reason why the number is a multiple of 4 for every graph (with 4 or more vertices): Dylan said that this is true for every graph with 4 vertices, and if the number is a multiple of $m$ for every graph with $n$ vertices it is a multiple of $m$ for every graph with $n+1$.

Comment: For one of them he says that the invariant is 14

Comment: It is a triangle with one extra vertex joined to one of the vertices.

Comment: @NickL: Ah, sorry, good catch. At any rate, the argument applies to trees, then.

Comment: @SamHopkins Triangle free would then be enough.

Comment: I don't understand the proposed relationship with the Tutte polynomial. All trees have the same Tutte polynomial, but the number you are interested in is different for different trees.

Comment: @TimothyChow it was just that the way of recursively computing it felt vaguely similar to the recursive computation of the Tutte polynomial. But it's really a stretch.

Comment: @DylanThurston For the Tutte polynomial, I can pick any edge, and recursively compute what happens when I delete or contract that edge. I don't need an outer loop over all possible choices of that edge. For your invariant, naively it seems that I need to loop over all possible choices of the first vertex to delete. Is that correct? Or is there a smarter recursive computation?

Comment: For the ``lollypop" graph  obtained by attaching one vertex $v$, to a vertex $w$ of an $n$-cycle, the sweeping number is $L_n=2^{n-2}\frac{n^2+n+2}2.$ Sketch: It works for $n=3.$ Deleting $v$ first leaves a cycle so $n\,2^{n-2}$ ways to finish. The sequences which delete $v$ on the second move all leave a path of length $n-1$ so there are  $(n-1)2^{n-2}$ of these.  The remaining ways amount to $2(L_{n-1}-(n-1)2^{n-3})$ because the two vertices deleted are (in one order or the other) the endpoints of an edge of the cycle not incident with $w.$

Comment: Suppose we add a "hair" to a graph $G$ i.e. add one edge and one vertex, to $v \in V_G$ giving $G'$. Then (calling the invariant $S$) we have $S(G') = S(G) + 2S(G \setminus v)$. This gives a pretty systematic way to compute the invariant for trees.